# What could render a person blind without any visible markings?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, magic

I am trying to create a character who is blind but she didn't always start out that way. What are some things that could lead to vision loss without any visible reason. Assuming this is a fantasy world with primitive technology, magic could also be sourced.

Comment: Ah, a spell that causes blindness?

Comment: Allowing magic, any answer is possible. This is an idea for a character in a story, it's opinion, and it's too broad, all of which are reasons to close.  How about bringing it up on [sandbox] to get it into better shape?

Comment: @JDługosz  I am very new to this platform.

Comment: I see, and welcome to WB!  It seems the link to sandbox didn't work… can you find your way to [meta]? I think it is an interesting idea if it can be made fit for this SE.  I didn't mean to be harsh to you, but noted this for people (other newbes) surfing in since it is getting a lot of views.

Comment: I could probably find it, and don't worry you weren't too harsh.

Comment: I wonder, how did you find your way to Worldbuilding, if not from another SE site? If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: @JDługosz I disagree with all of your close reasons. The question asks for a rationale for how something could have happened; not ideas for how to proceed with the story. Unless you want to close half the questions here, I think this one fits right in.

Comment: @JDługosz twas recommended on a world building site when I was searching for content to build my D&D world of Allands.

Comment: @MrLister in a way I am grateful, because you two led to an explanation of the platform that could help me in the future. Thank you both.

Comment: @MrLister I think it's worth discussing on Meta. “what can I have for dinner, btw magical items are allowed?” it doesn't involve overall culture or setting design, but is a specific question about a character with a fully generic setting.

Comment: I voted to close this question as Too Broad; there are a million (well, maybe not *that* many) possible answers. However, I'll note that Aify, JDługosz, and Hohmannfan voted to close as Primarily Opinion-Based, not Too Broad, for reasons @JDługosz articulated before.

Comment: @HDE226868 because there are so many answers, I'd love to see all of my options and decide what best fits in my world. I don't know the strict protocol that seems to be darting around but is it really necessary? It's not clutter.

Comment: @BritneySeereeram That's fine. The problem, though, is that there are many, many, many answers. You could choose almost anything. That, I think, played into the decision of those who voted to close as opinion-based: There's no objective criteria for deciding whether or not one answer is better than another. I'll see if I can get you more information on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Damage to the back of the brain, where vision is processed.

There is a number of ways this may happen, including eating vegetables that have been contaminated with tapeworm eggs. Instead of hatching in your gut, they hatch in your brain.

Given the technology level you mention, your characters will not have their eyes or brains scanned for a neural cause. They probably don't even know any brain anatomy, and much food hygiene basics yet.

Answer (score 6):

Methanol Poisoning. 10 ml of pure methanol can cause permanent blindness

Comment: I actually like this answer best amongst all answers here. Right to the point and very probable in a low tech setting.

Comment: Historically well known, as "denatured alcohol", i.e. industrial alcohol with toxic substances added to make it undrinkable, is often redistilled into drinking alcohol.  See for example https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/government-poison-10000-americans/ , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Irkutsk_mass_methanol_poisoning , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_methanol_poisoning_incidents  (Links focus on deaths but blindness from a lower dose is more common.)

Comment: The book "Like Water for Elephants" features methanol blindness from drinking US-Prohibition-era bootleg alcohol as a plot point.

Answer (score 5):

- staring at a bright light source for too long
- [diseases](http://www.healthline.com/symptom/blindness)
- [inattentional blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness)
- head trauma
- poison/venom
- magic

Answer (score 5):

It used to be called hysterical blindness, but has been redubbed [Conversion Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_disorder).  It refers to a psychological state where for reasons that differ from case to case, symptoms such as blindness are manifest without detectable biological cause.

As an author, it is always fun to play with psychology when magic is available because either can explain away the other and careful writing can keep the reader guessing which is which, right up to the final reveal.

Answer (score 5):

We had a student who went blind after being beaten on the back of the head in the area of the visual cortex of the brain. The doctors cannot find any visual reason for the blindness. At times it is like he sees things with his eyes but his brain does not communicate the information to the rest of the brain.

Answer (score 2):

[Pituitary tumor](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/000704.htm)?

[Blindness resulting from orbital complications of sinusitis.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1908969) Note however that from personal experience, someone with serious sinus infection would have reduced ability to do things like concentrate for a significant amount of time prior to the problem becoming so serious as to cause loss of vision. Of course there might be exceptions, I am only talking from personal experience. Oh, don't worry; it has not progressed that far for me, but I might need a hearing aid soon.

Comment: Sounds difficult, stay sane!

Answer (score 2):

Damage to the part of the brain that processes visual input, as others have stated.

Damage to the nerves between the eye and the part of the brain that processes visual input.

An acquired inability to produce photoreceptor cells (cones and rods).

If healing magic exists she could have had her eye damaged, waited (not necessarily by choice) until it scarred and then had healing magic cast on her which restored the eye but left the retina scarred.

You may also want to consider the possibility that she may not, in fact, be blind, but rather incapable of seeing for other reasons, for example because a spell has been placed on her which reflects all light before it hits the retina, one that places a constant light in front of the retina, drowning out all other light, or a deformation of the lens in the eye (this would cause extreme deformations in anything she sees, rendering her unable to see anything, but it would still allow her to determine if there is a lot of light or none at all).